# Reduction of hard to easy problem and vice versa

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, irreducible-polynomials, np-complete

$A\: \leq_m B$ means means $A$ cannot be harder than $B$  that means $B$ is atleast as hard as $A.$
And also I know  that "If $B$ is easy then $A$ is easy" and "If $A$ is hard then $B$ is hard"
But don't understand these two statements $:$

$(I)$ "If $B$ is hard then $A$ may or may not be hard. "

$(II)$ "If $A$ is easy then $B$ may or may not be easy."

Comment: What do you mean when you say you don't understand these statements? Do you mean you don't understand what the statements are saying, or that you don't know whether the statements are true?

Comment: @Mark I mean how these two statements are true.

Comment: Clearly, it's possible for both $A$ and $B$ to be either both easy or both hard - just take $A = B$ and pick an example of an easy question or a hard question. It's also possible for $A$ to be easy and $B$ to be hard.

Comment: @Mark don't understand.. Explain little bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it will help you to think of the $\leq_m$ relation as the usual $\leq$ ordering with "big" numbers being hard problems and "small" numbers being easy ones.

- $(I)$ is saying that if $a \leq 10^{1000}$, for example, then $a$ may or may not be a "big" number ($1 \leq 10^{1000}$ but at the same time $10^{1000}-1 \leq 10^{1000}$).
- $(II)$ on the other hand says that if $1 \leq b$, for example, then $b$ may or may not be a "small" number ($1 \leq 2$ but at the same time $1 \leq 10^{1000}$).